# Notational position of $dx$ in integral

Tags: integration, notation

In the Analysis courses in Aachen in the 1980s, an integral, whether Riemann or Lebesgue always had the form

$$ \int \text{stuff}\, d\text{var} $$

where the $\int$ and the $d\text{var}$ where used like braces to enclose the integrand 'stuff'. These days on the net and in books, often in the context of physics, I find a notation like

$$ \int d\text{var}\, \text{stuff}_1\, \text{stuff}_2 $$

where it seems that at least $\text{stuff}_1$, maybe even $\text{stuff}_2$, is the integrand. The situation is even more confusing if 'var' is not just a variable but a more elaborate expression. As an example consider the formula from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Formulation_in_the_physics_literature):

$$ f(H) = \int dE\, |\Psi_E\rangle \,f(E)\, \langle\Psi_E^{*}| $$

Where is $\text{var}$ and where is $\text{stuff}$ now?

*Questions:*

1. Am I right that the integrand is indeed written after the $d\text{var}$ in this case or am I over-interpreting and it is just identity that is integrated?
2. If the integrand is indeed written after the $d\text{var}$, then why? Is it just a different notational convention or does it have a subtly different meaning?

Comment: I don't see any benefits to using $\int dx f(x)$, but I could see cases of ambiguity arise.

Comment: Usually in physics there are some really extense and complicated expressions that might get difficult to know what you are integrating with respect to, at least that's what my physics professor once said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some lecturers in theoretical physics there at that time used this notation as well.
Comes in handy in formulas with many particles and 
$$
\int\limits\!\!dx^n\cdot
$$
is more operator style than
$$
\int\limits\!\cdot \,dx^n$$
Also note the habit of not specified integration domain meaning the full space.

Now this 
$$ 
f(H) = \int dE\, \left|\Psi_E\right\rangle \,f(E)\, \left\langle\Psi_E^{*}\right| 
$$
compare with a discrete energy spectrum
$$
f(H) = \sum_k\, \left|\Psi_{E_k}\right\rangle \,f(E_k)\, \left\langle\Psi_{E_k}^*\right| 
$$
where I am tempted to write the sum operator as $\sum_{E_k}$.

Regarding 1.: Everything behind the integral operator is integrand. (both $\mbox{stuff}_i$)

Regarding 2.: It is for convenience, for example to not loose oversight when several integrations are iterated ([example](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfadintegral#Herleitung)). It is also stressing the operator view.

Another example (ideal gas, grand canonical partition function):
$$
Z_{gk}(T,V,\mu) =
\sum_{N=0}^\infty\frac{e^{\beta\mu N}}{N!}
\int d^3 r_1 \cdots d^3 r_N e^{\beta V_N}
\int \frac{d^3 p_1 \cdots d^3 p_N}{h^{3N}}
e^{-\beta T_N}
$$
(Source: [Thermodynamik](http://www.statistische.physik.uni-rostock.de/fileadmin/Physik_Stat/TheoPhysV-Tdyn-Skripte.pdf), p. 90)

Answer (score 1):

Just a different use of notation that means the same thing, usually physicists, indeed, make use of $\int dx f(x)$ instead of $\int f(x) dx$.